# Check if a list is the exactly the same as the tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I was trying to make a program that if the user entered the exactly same data with the given tuple, it will print ('available'), else, if not, it will append the new data. But my program doesn't print 'available' even though I entered the exactly same data too.

```
data = ['Karma', 19, 'e', 'Kunugigaoka JH']
user = [input('name:'), int(input('age: ')), input('section: '), input('school: ')]
if user in data: 
    print('still available')
else: 
    data = data.append(user), print(data, 'your new data is now added')
```

What's the wrong code there? Was it the 'in' in the if statement, and how to fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a functioning version of your code.

```
data = [['Karma', 19, 'e', 'Kunugigaoka JH']]
user = [input('name:'), int(input('age: ')), input('section: '), input('school: ')]

if user in data:
    print('still available')
else:
    data.append(user)
    print(user, 'your new data is now added')
```

**Explanation**

- Your data format needs to be a list *of lists* in order for your program to work as anticipated.
- `list.append` does not `return` anything, so do not assign to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

`in` will check each element of your data.  So in the case of:

```
data = ['Karma', 19, 'e', 'Kunugigaoka JH']
```

it will check `'Karma'`, then `19`, then...

Instead you should try:

```
data = [['Karma', 19, 'e', 'Kunugigaoka JH']]
```

This is a list, in a list. Now the first thing `in` will check will be:

```
['Karma', 19, 'e', 'Kunugigaoka JH']
```

Comment: just make `data` a set and use `set.add()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands Lists cannot be members of sets.

Comment: @glibdud whoops yep, but those lists could be tuples possibly, depending on what they're doing next

Answer (score 0):

> **This answer is completly based on the title of this question:**

Let's say you have:

```
>>>a = [1,2,3] #REMEMBER for this method to work the list and tuple should be in exact oder
>>>b = (1,2,3)

>>>all( [i==j for i,j in zip(a,b)] )
True
>>>b = (3,2,1) #Here though a and b have the same elements but not the same order
>>>all( [i==j for i,j in zip(a,b)] )
Flase
```